# Calculate a value for 2 different set of IDs in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

My excel table has 5 Rows: Id, ColA, ColB, Count and Test.

```
ID  A   B   Count  Test
2   a  low   5     -
2   b  high  6     -
2   c  low   7     - 
2   d  high  8     -
2   e  low   9     -
1   a  low   1    =(1-5)
1   l  high  2    -
1   e  low   3    =(3-9)
```

I want to Calculate the value of Test for only rows with Id = 1

```
If Value of ColA for ID 1 = Value of of ColA for ID 2 and 
   Value of ColB for ID 1 = Value of of ColB for ID 2
then calculate the difference between the Count Values 
else
0
```

The Excel Table is connected to Sql Query. Every time I refresh it the table has a different number of rows.

I tried using VLOOKUP in TEST column where Id = 1 and specified the array table as the first 5 rows (only with Id = 2) but it doesn't seem to work because when I refresh the table the second time there are only 2 rows for Id = 2.

I want the TEST column value to be automatically calculated each time the table is refreshed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use countifs to find if it exists, and sumifs to return the value:

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,A:A,2)),D2-SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,C:C,C2,A:A,2),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on my question. The formula works fine as long as I have alphabets or numbers in the column. For example: If A2 has a value of <100 and A7 also has the same value <100 - I am getting 0 in E7. Any reason??

Comment: because they use a string as the criteria and it is reading it as anything less than 100 not `<100`  to overcome that we need to add `"="&` in front of the criteria like `"="&"<100"` then it will see it as a literal string.

Comment: Thanks!! Very Helpful